# How do I embed views programmatically in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin

I'm trying to set up a user interface programmatically using Xamarin. (c#). How do I embed say Navigation Controllers, Tab bar controllers, and page controllers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may be of use to you: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tab_bar/create_a_tab_bar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place this in your AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching

```
        var tab = new UITabBarController ();

        var nav1 = new UINavigationController (new MyViewController1 ());
        var nav2 = new UINavigationController (new MyViewController2 ());
        var nav3 = new UINavigationController (new MyViewController3 ());

        tab.ChildViewControllers = new [] { nav1, nav2, nav3 };

        Window.RootViewController = tab;
```

Comment: Do I need to import anything? Also where do I put this? Please update your answer with more specifics and I will accept your answer

Comment: You put this on AppDelegate to replace the root view controller